# How to write a program that checks if a word supplied as the argument is an Isogram

Tags: python, methods, boolean, tuples

I need to write this python code to check if a word is isogram, and was asked to use a method and call a tuple before ending up with a boolean. Here is the test code I was given, I have battled with this code for over a day with no solution.

```
from unittest import TestCase

class IsogramTestCases(TestCase):
  def test_checks_for_isograms(self):
    word = 'abolishment'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, True),
      msg="Isogram word, '{}' not detected correctly".format(word)
    )

  def test_returns_false_for_nonisograms(self):
    word = 'alphabet'
    self.assertEqual(
      is_isogram(word),
      (word, False),
      msg="Non isogram word, '{}' falsely detected".format(word)
    )

  def test_it_only_accepts_strings(self):
    with self.assertRaises(TypeError) as context:
      is_isogram(2)
      self.assertEqual(
        'Argument should be a string',
        context.exception.message,
        'String inputs allowed only'
      )
```

Comment: Where is the code you tested and did not work. Hard to know what actually went wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: Could you explain the relevancy of the shown code and give examples of desired inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can test for an isogram with `len(set(s)) == len(s)` That is to say that the string is an isogram if the length of the set of unique characters equals the the length of the string.

Seems to me that the function would look like this:

```
def is_isogram(s):
    if not isinstance(s, str):
       raise TypeError('String inputs allowed only')
    return len(set(s)) == len(s)
```